# Imageresizer : wrong cropping behavior

Tags: c#, image, image-resizing, imageresizer

I would like to render all images with the same size even those which are to small.

If I render bigger images like this: `?width=768&height=365&mode=crop` it would be fine but not for the small images.

When I add the `scale=canvas` property the bigger Images are zoomed in. Can I somehow prevent this behavior?

See examples bellow:

**`?width=768&height=365&mode=crop`** 
[image]

**`?width=768&height=365&mode=crop&scale=canvas`**
[image]

**`?width=768&height=365&mode=crop&scale=canvas`**
[image]

**`?width=768&height=365&mode=crop`**
[image]

Comment: Doe the 3rd and 4th images represent expected behavior?

Comment: The 3rd image is fine at all but the 2nd should be like the 1st even with the scale=canvas property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mode=crop` and `mode=pad&scale=canvas` offer two mutually exclusive ways to resolve an aspect ratio difference between the image itself and what you're asking for.

- `mode=crop` -> Removes data
- `mode=pad` -> Adds space to resolve aspect ratio difference.
- `scale=canvas` -> Adds blank space if the image is smaller than requested

We *should* have tested how `mode=crop` and `scale=canvas` interact, but we *didn't*. The behavior here is completely undefined.

Comment: Do you have a solution how I can reach those effects for now?

Comment: If you're OK with white space, `mode=pad&scale=canvas` is most commonly used. If you don't mind upscaling, `mode=crop&scale=both` should work properly.

Comment: Will this use case be considered in the next release?

Comment: Already created [an issue for it](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/issues/168). Can't estimate when it will be released.